# Best way to redirect old URLs

Tags: url, redirect, plugin-retour, uri

It has been recommended to me to change our URL structure from:

`site.com/yyyy/mm/dd/slug`

to

`site.com/variable-element/slug`

where the variable may be two segments.

Is this something Retour can do, or is there a tag that would recognise segment four as a slug and 'find' the correct new URL?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own redirect.

Add a route in `/admin/settings/routes`

Declare it like so:

[image: route definition]

Create a new template `templates/page/_redirect.twig`:

```
{% set requestedSlug = craft.app.request.getSegment(4) %}

{% set redirectToEntry = craft.entries()
.slug(requestedSlug|literal)
.one() %}

{% redirect redirectToEntry.url %}
```

That should redirect nicely.

Comment: Oh amazing, thank you!